# Fundamental solution to the bi-harmonic operator?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

[image]

I am not sure about what the hint means.

If $\Delta u =\frac{1}{2 \pi}(1+\log|x|)$. Since $\log|x|$ is a fundamental solution of $\Delta u =0$. Does that mean $\frac{1}{2 \pi}(1+\log|x|)$ is a fundamental solution of $\Delta u=0$, so the $\frac{-1}{8 \pi}|x|^2\log|x|$ is a fundamental solution of $\Delta \Delta u$?

Is that right? Can anyone help me? I feel the argument is not sufficient. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's basically an exercise in distributional notation: Take $u(x)=-\frac{|x|^2}{8\pi}\ln|x|$ and $v(x)=-(2\pi)^{-1}(1+\ln|x|)$, then we have

$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}u\Delta^2 \varphi dx := \langle \Delta^2 u, \varphi \rangle = \langle \Delta u, \Delta \varphi \rangle =\langle v, \Delta \varphi \rangle.
$$
(where the brackets denote the dual pairing of a distribution and a test function). If $v$ is a fundamental solution for $\Delta$, then the last term is by definition $\langle \Delta v, \varphi\rangle = \varphi(0)$.